# Center an equation with align

Tags: align

I would like to center my equation but when I am using \align, I don't know why it is not center whereas all of my previous equations, there are centered.
Please find my code down below

```
\begin{align*}
(\lambda + 0.1459)(0.0409 \times 267)=& 0 \\
\lambda^2 + (0.1459 + 0.2052) \lambda + 0.1459 \times 0.2052 + 0.0409 \times 267 =& 0 \\
\lambda^2 + 0.3511 \lambda +10.9502 =& 0 
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Thank you for your help :D

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: note you should use `&=` not `=&` otherwise you will not get relation spacing around the =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351223/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
(\lambda + 0.1459)(0.0409 \times 267)&= 0 \\
\lambda^2 + (0.1459 + 0.2052) \lambda + 0.1459 \times 0.2052 + 0.0409 \times 267& = 0 \\
\lambda^2 + 0.3511 \lambda +10.9502 &= 0 
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete document, which begin with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}
- Your equation are centered and aligned at sign `=` despite that ampersands are on wrong side of `=` (it should be before `=` and not after).
- It is not clear, what you mean with "centered". If you not like to have just centered and not aligned  adt equal sign,  than use `gather` environment and remove ampersands (see the second example in MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{align*}
(\lambda + 0.1459)(0.0409 \times 267)
    & = 0 \\
\lambda^2 + (0.1459 + 0.2052) \lambda + 0.1459 \times 0.2052 + 0.0409 \times 267 
    & = 0 \\
\lambda^2 + 0.3511 \lambda +10.9502 
    & = 0
\end{align*}
\begin{gather*}
(\lambda + 0.1459)(0.0409 \times 267)
    = 0 \\
\lambda^2 + (0.1459 + 0.2052) \lambda + 0.1459 \times 0.2052 + 0.0409 \times 267
    = 0 \\
\lambda^2 + 0.3511 \lambda +10.9502
    = 0
\end{gather*}
```

[image]